# VTK 5.8 on Xcode 4 (Lion)

Tags: xcode, vtk, itk

I was trying to compile and start with VTK project on my Xcode under OS X
Lion. 
I followed the instructions here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/Cocoa_VTK to
download and compile vtk using cmake (although I did avoid setting the mac
osx deployment target to 10.4)

I presume that, under a new Xcode project, all I need is to set vtk's
include folder under the header search path, and vtk's lib folder under
'Other linker flags'.

However I am unable to proceed, Xcode gives me an error message: 
'Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1'

Following is my header search path: 
/Users/mycomp/VTKBuild/include/**

and other linker flags: 
/Users/mycomp/VTKBuild/lib/vtk-5.8

Apparently the problem disappears when I clear out the 'Other linker flags',
but of course it means that I am not referring to VTK's library anymore.

Is there anything I am missing ? And is there any updated guide on how to
start on VTK-related project under Xcode 4.0 ?

Comment: It's generally better/easier to just add the header and library directories to the project and then you don't need to mess with include paths or linker flags

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late to answer this perhaps, but that seems to be some strange "other linker flags".

I think you could just add the library you are linking with into "Build Phases -> Link Binary with libraries" and then add a library path to the containing folder in "Library search paths" under "Build settings".

You could also get more information about the reason behind the failure if you look into the build itself.